# How to execute WorkflowApplication Synchronously

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

I would like to execute workflow using WorkflowApplication synchronously on calling thread.

Link http://msmvps.com/blogs/theproblemsolver/archive/2011/01/07/doing-synchronous-workflow-execution-using-the-workflowapplication.aspx provides one example but Idle and Abort events are still being executed on separate threads.

Is there something in framework that already provides full sync execution or I will have to write it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The workflow runtime, regardless of the host you choose, is always asynchronous. There is nothing you can do about it beyond using a different SynchronizationContext or blocking the thread until the workflow is done. Ron Jacobs has a similar approach using a ManualResetEvent with his [Workflow Episodes](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rjacobs/archive/2011/02/08/wf4-workflow-episodes.aspx).

Comment: Pfft.  Manual reset events.  All my reset events are auto.

Comment: Thanks. This helped. I ended up developing more advanced SynchronizationContext that enables executing all events on calling thread.

Answer (score 0):

Two years later... The best way is :

```
class SynchronousSynchronizationContext : SynchronizationContext
{
    public override void Post(SendOrPostCallback d, object state)
    {
        this.Send(d, state);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not that simple. Idle and Abort events are being invoked on new thread from the one you are invoking workflow application. So this will only work if you have workflows that won't have those events.